# Fixing the date axis of a time series in vba

Tags: vba, excel, graph, charts

I have a code that gets data from excel and makes a graph. It takes some inputs (since more than one graph is done), creates a new Chart Sheet and insert the data.

**Problem 1** My code gets the UsedRange from the specified sheet and uses that to fill the graph. The data starts at A1 and goes until the end. One of the Graphs however, have data in its first row that should not go into the graph. Foe example:

This is for one of the normal graphs:

```
           Item 1         Item 2
 day 1      100            100
 day 2      110            180
 day 3       90            110
 day 4       70            130
```

and so on. This is the exception:

```
           Item 1         Item 2
 day 1        1              1
 day 2      110            180
 day 3       90            110
 day 4       70            130
```

**QUESTION 1** In this second case, I want to remove the first row of data (not the identifier row) from the graph. Since I am using UsedRage, how can that be done?

**Problem 2** For all the graphs, the data series start at some point in the past and comes until today. Problem is that when the date series is graphed, it starts counting from the first day (stepping through the periods, eg. 6 months) until it reaches the most recent date.

In this case, it does not include today's date, which is what I am trying to achieve.

**To exemplify:**[image: GraphExample]

In this case, my data goes until the 7th of December, but the last date that appears is the 31st of October.

**QUESTION 2** Can this be fixed?

Obs: I already tried using the recorder to generate a code for this, but even in the embedded excel options I cannot find any way to do it.

**The code so far:**

```
Function Grapher(ChartSheetName As String, SourceWorksheet As String, ChartTitle As String, secAxisTitle As String)

Dim lColumn As Long, lRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim RetChart As Chart
Dim w As Workbook
Dim RetRange As Range
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim p As Integer
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim numMonth As Long
Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date

Set w = ThisWorkbook

'find limit
LastColumn = w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).Cells(1,   w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
LastRow = w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).Cells(w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If SourceWorksheet <> "DD" Then 'this is the exception case    
    Set RetRange = w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).UsedRange 'HOW CAN i CHANGE THE RANGE TO ACCOUNT FOR THE PROBLEM 1?     
Else    
    Set RetRange = w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).UsedRange                    
End If

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
For Each chrt In w.Charts
    If chrt.Name = ChartSheetName Then
        Set RetChart = chrt
        RetChart.Activate
        p = 1
    End If
Next chrt
If p <> 1 Then
    Set RetChart = Charts.Add
End If
'count the number of months in the time series, do the ratio
d1 = w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).Range("A2").Value
d2 = w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).Range("A" & LastRow).Value    
numMonth = TestDates(d1, d2)                
x = Round((numMonth / 15), 1)        
'ratio to account for period size
If x < 3 Then
    y = 1
ElseIf x >= 3 And x < 7 Then
    y = 4
ElseIf x > 7 Then
    y = 6
End If            
'create chart
        With RetChart
            .Select
            .ChartType = xlLine
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = ChartTitle
            .SetSourceData Source:=RetRange
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = secAxisTitle
            .Name = ChartSheetName
            .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
            .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlLow
            .Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = y
            .Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnitScale = xlMonths
        End With
End Function
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Function TestDates(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date) As Long
TestDates = DateDiff("m", pDate1, pDate2)
End Function
```

Any Help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: The first row (where "Item1" and "item2" is a header row?

Comment: @A.S.H Exactly. The row I want to exclude is the

    day 1        1              1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of tinkering with the code and help from other posts and people, I could finally solve problem 1.

**Problem 1** Can be solved by setting the range to total and than resetting the data when the graph is created. The code for it is (to be added within the "with"):

```
If SourceWorksheet = "DD" Then
                For lColumn = 2 To LastColumn

                    .FullSeriesCollection(lColumn - 1).Name = "=DD!$" & Col_Letter(lColumn) & "$1"
                    .FullSeriesCollection(lColumn - 1).Values = "=DD!$" & Col_Letter(lColumn) & "$3:$" & Col_Letter(lColumn) & "$" & LastRow

                Next lColumn

            End If

        End With
```

**Problem 2** I have been scavenging the internet, but apparently there is not way to step backwards and then mirror the graph, so that remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

If the start cell should be `A2` you could try this:

`Set RetRange = w.Sheets(SourceWorksheet).Range("A2:C" & LastRow)`

Problem 2:

I see on your graph that the interval of the data shown on X axis is 4 months. As i know there is no way to force excel to make an irregular interval and force show additional label for last value.

You could try adding a label to the last data point: 
[label-last-point](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/label-last-point.htm)

**EDIT: Added screen to my comment**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Problem 1: That is what I am currently doing: I set the beginning of the cell to that and then restate the series name directly in the graphing part.
Problem 2: What I am currently trying to do, is find a way for excel to count the dates backwards, therefore I would have the last date (stepping 4 or 6 months back) until the matching date in the beginning, then the first beginning dates do not appear, which is acceptable. Problem is I cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: The other thing you could try is to change the series format from dates to text. Excel will treat it differently and you should get more options on customizing the axis labels.

Comment: @DGMS89 Try This: `.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).ReversePlotOrder = True`

Comment: @ A.S.H. It will reverse the graph but as i recall the last value will not have a label.

Comment: @A.S.H I tried it before, but checking any time series backwards would be counter intuitive. The only way I imagine it could work is if there was a way to mirror the plot part of the graph in the output. But that goes against the purpose of the line of code you suggested. If I could count the dates backwards but past them normally, it would be solved.

Comment: Sorry then, I totally misuderstood part 2.